# AzureDevOps.GetWorkItemDetails not returning fields data

Tags: azure-devops, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I'm trying to build a simple view of Work Items and Work Item Details in a Canvas PowerApp, and am running into issues with GetWorkItemDetails giving me the data I'm looking for.

Here's my code to display the Repro Steps field from the Bug work item type.

```
Text(AzureDevOps.GetWorkItemDetails(Gallery2.Selected.Value.'System.Id', Account, Project, "Bug").fields.'System.Repro Steps')
```

This is not returning anything, although I do get data back for these fields:

```
Text(AzureDevOps.GetWorkItemDetails(Gallery2.Selected.Value.'System.Id', Account, Project, "Bug").id)
Text(AzureDevOps.GetWorkItemDetails(Gallery2.Selected.Value.'System.Id', Account, Project, "Bug").url)
```

Any ideas on how to debug this? I know I'm doing something wrong with the "fields" property - I've tried fields.repro_steps, fields.'Repro Steps', etc. Nothing seems to work...

**UPDATE:** I think it has something to do with either how "GetWorkItemDetails" works, or potentially how the PowerApps Custom Connector is deciding which fields to bring back. I took a step back and tried a couple more variations...

```
// this works
Gallery1.Selected.Value.'Custom.Category'

// this doesn't work
AzureDevOps.GetWorkItemDetails(Gallery1.Selected.Value.'System.Id', Account, Project, "Bug").fields.'Custom.Category'

// alas, this doesn't work either
Gallery1.Selected.Value.'Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the issue is that the field name used in the AzureDevOps.GetWorkItemDetails is not correct.

You can change to use the value **Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps** to represent the Repo Steps field.

> Any ideas on how to debug this?

To get the correct name of the field, I suggest that you can use this Rest API: [Field-List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/fields/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/fields?api-version=7.1-preview.3
```

For example:

[image]

**Update:**

When using the AzureDevOps.GetWorkItemDetail, you can use the following two format to access the work item field.

For example: replace Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps with Microsoft_VSTS_TCM_ReproSteps.   **fields.Microsoft_VSTS_TCM_ReproSteps**

```
Text(AzureDevOps.GetWorkItemDetails(Gallery2.Selected.Value.'System.Id', Account, Project, "Bug").fields.Microsoft_VSTS_TCM_ReproSteps)
```

Or keep using the  Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps, but we need to use the format: **value.'Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps'**

For example:

```
Text(AzureDevOps.GetWorkItemDetails(Gallery2.Selected.Value.'System.Id', Account, Project, "Bug").value.'Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps')
```

Comment: I originally accepted this because I thought it was working, but it seems to only work through the web API directly. When I tried it in my code I thought it was OK, but it's not working. See the "UPDATE" section in the question post above for more details. Maybe it's a setting somewhere, or a configuration somewhere that I'm missing? I seem to remember that doing this via Flow requires you to ask for specific fields to come back, but I could be mixing that up with something else...

Comment: @ChrisKoenig Please check the update in the answer. We can use the following two format to access the work item field. **Text(ThisItem.Value.'System.Id')** or **Text(ThisItem.fields.System_Id)**

Comment: OK - the updates worked, at least the first version. the ".value.'Microsoft,VSTS..." that did NOT work, but the "fields.Microsoft_VSTS_... did. THANK YOU!